# Best way to pass multi-dimensional array as 1D array

Tags: fortran

I have a subroutine that populates a rank 1 array of arbitrary length.

```
subroutine populate_array_1D(array)
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:), intent(out) :: array
    array(:) = 1
end subroutine populate_array_1D
```

I now want to modify this routine using overloading to accept higher-dimensioned arrays.

```
interface populate_array
    module procedure populate_array_1D, populate_array_2D, populate_array_3D
end interface populate_array
```

What I want to do is to refer the higher-dimensioned subroutines back to the 1D subroutine.

My ideas so far:

1. Slice the array, and pass the slices one-by-one:

   ```
   subroutine populate_array_2D(array)
       implicit none
       integer, dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: array
       integer :: i
       do i = lbound(array, 2), ubound(array, 2)
           call populate_array_1D(array(:, i))
       end do
   end subroutine populate_array_2D
   ```
2. Create a new, automatic 1D array, and then use `reshape`:

   ```
   subroutine populate_array_3D(array)
       implicit none
       integer, dimension(:,:,:), intent(out) :: array
       integer :: tmp_array(size(array))
       call populate_array_1D(tmp_array)
       array = reshape(tmp_array, shape(array))
   end subroutine populate_array_3D
   ```

Assume that, like in this example, the result of either version will be okay, I'm only worried about the performance. (I should probably add that I can't just make an `elemental` subroutine because it can't be `pure`.)

Or is there an even better version, where I can pass a multidimensional array into a subroutine pretending it's a 1D array?

(Ultimately I want to replace the call to `RANDOM_NUMBER` with a PRNG that is as deterministic as possible across different compilers and/or machines, assuming they use the same seed.)

Comment: Elemental subroutines can be impure.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that you can specify `impure elemental`. Thanks @francescalus

Answer (score 1):

As francescalus pointed out, elemental procedures can be impure (as of Fortran 2008).

Alternatively, you could use Fortran's intrinsic C interoperability
to gain low-level access to the memory location of the 2D array. The following subroutine builds a 1D pointer to the 2D array:

```
subroutine populate_array_2D(array)
    use iso_c_binding, only: C_F_POINTER, C_LOC

    integer, dimension(:,:), target, contiguous, intent(out) :: array

    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: ptr_1d

    call C_F_POINTER (C_LOC(array), ptr_1d, [size(array)])
    call populate_array_1D(ptr_1d)
end subroutine populate_array_2D
```

#### Edit:

The call to `c_f_pointer` can be replaced by
the equivalent bound-remapping list in the pointer:
`ptr_1d(1:size(array)) => array`
(though compiling with ifort18 gives an erroneous [warning message](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fdiag8589) that this is not valid Fortran 2008).

Comment: `Error: Argument X at (1) to C_LOC shall have either the POINTER or the TARGET attribute`    But given your assumption that `array` is contiguous, why don't you give it both the `CONTIGUOUS` and `TARGET` attributes so you can use array bounds remapping to point `ptr_1d` at it directly?    `ptr_1d(1:size(array)) => array`

Comment: You're right about the `target` attribute, thanks for catching that. (Ifort doesn't.) 

But a bound remapping list for the pointer is not standard-conforming. I had initially intended to mention this, but I forgot.

Comment: No, you haven't read the standard on this issue. I added an edit to your post that fleshes out my ideas and compiles on both ifort and gfortran. You forgot the `CONTIGUOUS` attribute on `rank2_array` in your edit.

Comment: As @user5713492 points out, a rank-2 array may be a target for a bounds-remapping pointer assignment as long as it is simply contiguous.

Comment: But this seems like a lot of effort to go to to avoid `integer array(*)`.

Comment: Here are my reasons for thinking that the rank-2 data target is not standard-conforming.

First, the second code block in the answer compiles for me as well, but ifort18 gives `warning #8589: Fortran 2015 specifies that if a bound remapping list is specified, data target must be of rank one.   [RANK2_ARRAY]`. Second, this is also what I read in Metcalf, Reid, Cohen, "Modern Fortran Explained (2011)", who state (in section 15.6) that *the target of a multidimensional array pointer may be one-dimensional*. (In their example they awkwardly avoid pointing directly to a matrix.)

Comment: Whether this is a lot of effort to avoid `integer array(*)` really depends. Besides the `use` statement, it is just two lines of code (the decla for the pointer and the call to C_F_POINTER).  I have found this solution useful once or twice. For example, when solving the linear system A_{ijk} x_i = b_{jk} in a single Lapack call.

Comment: N2137 section 10.2.2.3: If bounds-remapping-list appears ... the pointer target shall be simply contiguous (9.5.4) or of rank one ...

Comment: I was wrong, thank you. I was thrown off by ifort's erroneous warning I'll edit the answer.